# Is it likely that Snapchat & Whatsapp use AVFoundation on iOS?

Tags: swift, compression, avfoundation, whatsapp, snapchat

And if yes, is it likely they use the class below to give them a JPEG image in order to make compression easier?

```
class func jpegPhotoDataRepresentation(forJPEGSampleBuffer JPEGSampleBuffer: 
CMSampleBuffer, 
previewPhotoSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?) -> Data?
```

Answer (score -2):

On the question alone, "Is it likely that Snapchat & Whatsapp use AVFoundation on iOS?"; The answer is yes. According to SuperPowered Audio Framework they have found there is no way to play audio without using AVFoundation on IOS. I also haven't seen a camera app that doesn't use AVFoundation in some form. As far as photo compression goes, I would guess multi-billion dollar apps such as Snapchat and KIK would make a low level compression algorithm in C or C++ that would fit their exact compression needs rather than use AVFoundation and Swift/Objective C. The other reason they would likely have their own compression algorithm is because they would want their app to work in Android or Windows just like it would work in IOS. By creating their own compression algorithm they have a standardized app that looks and works nearly the same in every mobile OS.

Comment: Thank you, you make an interesting point that those firms would want Android and iOS to work equally well. Although that would explain why Instagram's iOS compression is better than their Android one ^^

Comment: Just as a follow up do you think that prior to these firms having armada's of engineers they used JPEG algorithms that are publicly available on the internet?

Comment: Yes actually! This is google's JPG encoder. https://github.com/google/guetzli/  I am sure you can find one of these algorithms for IOS.

Comment: Thanks! I actually found Guetzli for iOS as well, seems pretty good especially because it works lossy as well

Comment: Well I am happy I could help you! :) Can you click the check mark next to my answer if you think I answered your question well?